# Azure Cloud Service keeps regenerating

Tags: c#, wcf, azure

I have 2 cloud services hosted on Azure. The first is for database synchronization using MS Sync Framework 2.1 and the second hosts a utility WCF web service. Every so often I find that the cloud services have been regenerated (recreated). I know this because when I remote desktop to them the VM desktop runs through setup as in a first run situation. The problem is that my first cloud service required the Sync Framework 2.1 to work and my second has a virtual directory that I use for a ClickOnce application download.

When the cloud services are regenerated both the Sync Framework and my virtual directory are removed and I need to reinstall Sync Framework 2.1 and recreate my virtual directory. I have been on the MSDN forum but the only answer I received told me to make sure the country/region of the VMs are set the same as my work PC. This made no difference.

Comment: Are you installing software/creating virtual directory by connecting to the Cloud Service VM via RDP?

Comment: A follow-on to @GauravMantri's question: When you say Cloud Services, are you specifically talking about web/worker role instances?

Comment: Gaurav, Yes I am installing the Sync FX 2.1 and creating the virtual directory on the VM via RDP.

Comment: David, Yes I am talking about web roles. Each cloud service only has one instance.